# .NET retrieving values from dynamically created controls in a placeholder

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a .net web form, C# backend.

I need help looping through nested controls in a placeholder. I have a single placeholder, where I am basically creating dynamic form controls on the fly based on the data coming back from a stored procedure. The placeholder has a single Table which is created on the fly. This table is populated with checkboxes, and textboxes (they are "attached" to each other, by id... not really attached, but they have the same numeric id component).

I need some help looping through the placeholder, and the table to detect:
which checkboxes are checked, and what data is in the textboxes. Not ALL checkboxes have textboxes.

ASP.NET

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="phMyStuff" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

C#

```
using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        MyFlag= bool.Parse(dr["MyFlag"].ToString());

        CheckBox CB = new CheckBox();
        CB.Text = dr["StuffName"].ToString();
        CB.ID = dr["StuffID"].ToString();


        TableRow TR = new TableRow();
        TableCell TD = new TableCell();
        TD.Controls.Add(CB);
        TR.Controls.Add(TD);

        if (MyFlag== true)
        {
            TextBox TB = new TextBox();
            TB.ID = string.Format("tb_{0}", dr["StuffID"].ToString());
            TB.Width = 100;
            TableCell TD2 = new TableCell();
            TD2.Controls.Add(TB);
            TR.Controls.Add(TD2);

        }
        myTable.Controls.Add(TR);
    }
}
conn.Close();
conn.Dispose();

phMyStuff.Controls.Add(myTable);
```

the two pieces of data I am after in this loop are:

1. The ID of the checkboxes that are checked
2. The value of any textboxes that were created in the placeholder

Comment: put breakpoints in the code use the debugger to step through and evaluate also I don't see anywhere where you are setting the checkboxes checked state.. for example I would expect to see `CB.Checked = true;` meaning you need to check the value of the `dr["someCheckedValue"]`

Comment: `also I would recommend using bool.TryParse(dr["MyFlag"].ToString());`

Comment: There is no checked state at this point. These are dynamic form controls which are created on the fly. They go into a checked state once someone checks them, and are read for the checked state after the form is posted.

Comment: the what is the purpose of what you stated in item `1.` ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your code to load the data occurs on every PostBack using the same id's for each control each time and do the following:

```
protected void btnGetControlIds_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetControlIds(phMyStuff);
}

private void GetControlIds(Control parent) 
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in parent.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl is TextBox || ctrl is CheckBox)
        {
            Response.Write(ctrl.ID);
        }
        else
        {
            if (ctrl.HasControls())
            {
                GetControlIds(ctrl);
            }
        }
    }
}
```